# How do you calculate DST?

Tags: coldfusion, timezone, dst

I want to send notifications to users in different timezones on a date and time they provide. 
I haven't implemented anything yet, but I plan to create a timestamp column and store everything in UTC. At the time of submission, the user will select a timezone and I will calculate the offset, add it to the timestamp column, and voila.

I wish it were that simple, but my plan lacks DST. I have no way of finding out if the user is in DST or not.

How do I get around this? Do I need extra columns? Is there a better approach than what I'm planning?

Comment: Why do you have no way of finding out if the user is in DST? Will you *physically* lack the capability to provide form fields on your application that read "Choose Timezone" and "Automatically handle daylight savings time"--which is typical in these sorts of apps.

Comment: @Shawn, I plan to store the timezone. For example: Joe wants to receive a message at 13:00 in NYC. My server will store this as Now() + 5, which makes it 18:00. I will store the current server time + offset, and the timezone string. But I can't find a funciton in CF that will tell me if a timezone is in DST. I need this to adjust the offset. Like I said, I'm feeling my way in the dark here, so I could be completely off the wall. I've never done this before, so I don't know the right way to do it.

Comment: I don't know how to handle the "automatically handle day DST" part in CF.

Comment: The answer below is correct, I just misunderstood your phrasing--you made it sound ("I have no way of finding") like you were restricted in the design of your app to ask the user what their timezone/dst preferences were.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the java TimeZone object.

```
<cfset tzObj = createObject("java","java.util.TimeZone") >
```

You can get a list of available IDs e.g. "US/Pacific" by doing this

```
<cfset tzList = arrayToList(tzObj.getAvailableIDs()) >
```

If you can match the ID to your users region/time zone you can do the following:

```
tzToTest = "US/Pacific"
dateTotest = now()

<!--- determines if dateTotest in tzToTest is in DST --->
<cfset tz = tzObj.getTimeZone(tzToTest) />
<cfset isDaylightSavings = tz.inDaylightTime(dateTotest) />
```

Comment: That's the one, Barry. Cheers. Does it sound right doing it the way I am?

Comment: Yep, if you are storing the customers timezone you should have all you need. Dig into java.util.TimeZone, you'll find plenty of other useful functions in there, particularly around UTC. Cheers.